# Ubuntu Log in Message Confusion

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I have Ubuntu Lucid Lynx server installed on a machine which I access via SSH. Since few days when I log into system, I am getting following welcome screen after logging in.

```
Linux ubuntuserver 2.6.32-32-server #62-Ubuntu SMP Wed 
                              Apr 20 22:07:43 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS

Welcome to the Ubuntu Server!
 * Documentation:  http://www.ubuntu.com/server/doc

  System information as of Tue Jun 14 11:07:26 PDT 2011

  System load:  0.05               Processes:           144
  Usage of /:   1.9% of 447.72GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 41%                IP address for eth0: 192.168.1.14
  Swap usage:   0%

  => There is 1 zombie process.

  Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/

3 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS

Welcome to the Ubuntu Server!
 * Documentation:  http://www.ubuntu.com/server/doc

  System information as of Wed May  4 09:07:52 PDT 2011

  System load:  0.01               Processes:           137
  Usage of /:   1.3% of 447.72GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 20%                IP address for eth0: 192.168.1.14
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/

36 packages can be updated.
3 updates are security updates.

No mail.
Last login: Mon Jun 13 09:21:13 2011 from 182.64.117.115
```

The information is repeated but it is not same also it is for two different dates. Is this normal or I have smoked something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the login message is in `/etc/motd`. Check if the file contains both repetitions or only one.

If the file contains both, just edit it manually – it could be that Ubuntu's MOTD autoupdate script went crazy or something.

---

If `motd` only contains one half, try to find the other:

```
grep -L -r "information as of Wed" /etc /var
```

When you get file name, repeat the search: `grep -r "thefilename" /etc`

Comment: it was repeated twice in `motd`

Answer (score 1):

Look into /etc/motd.tail. The contents of this file are appended to /etc/motd on login. The second part of the message is probably in this file. Clear it out and the 'repeated' message will be gone on the next login.

Comment: thanks for reply, it was fixed by `sudo apt-get autoremove` I think I had not run this command for long.